# Play youtube video in video player

Tags: android, youtube, video-streaming

I want to play a video from youtube in my app. But i dont want to use Youtube application for that. I prefer native videoplayer. I have written the below code for that. But nothing is happening. Only a black screen is displaying.

```
         String link= getIntent().getExtras().get("url").toString();
         VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);
         MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
         mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
         Uri video = Uri.parse(link);
         videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
         videoView.setVideoURI(video);
         videoView.start();
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: debug your code and check the video url are coming into String variable are not and let me know..

Answer (score 0):

just simply do it like that hope it's work:

```
String link= getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);
    Uri video = Uri.parse(link);
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    videoView.start();
```

Comment: have u debugg ur code??and the video path(url )are u getting correctly?can you please send me the video path i will test on my side and let u know if it's working or not..